# Collecting terms of even exponents

Tags: polynomials

Say I've got a polynomial of $4$ or $5$ variables (we'll say $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_3$, and $d_4$). How would you collect the terms where each $d$ is raised to an even power? It collects the terms of the polynomial that are of the form

$$
d_1^{2 \cdot k_1} \cdot d_2^{2 \cdot k_2} \cdot d_3^{2 \cdot k_3} \cdot d_4^{2 \cdot k_4}
$$

for $k_1,\dotsc,k_5$ being integers.

Example:

$$
d_1^2 \cdot d_2^4 \cdot d_3^2 \cdot d_4^0 + d_1^0 \cdot d_2^3 \cdot d_3^2 \cdot d_4^3
$$

would take the

$$
d_1^2 \cdot d_2^4 \cdot d_3^2 \cdot d_4^0
$$

term and not the

$$
d_1^0 \cdot d_2^3 \cdot d_3^2 \cdot d_4^3
$$

term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CoefficientRules` has all this information build into it.

```
p = Expand[(x + y + z + w)^4];
vars = {x, y, z, w};
r = CoefficientRules[p, vars];
FromCoefficientRules[Pick[r, And @@ EvenQ[#[[1]]] & /@ r], vars]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: nice...always learn something

Comment: Nice indeed; a bit shorter: `FromCoefficientRules[Cases[r, {__?EvenQ} ~_~ _], vars]`

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution: let's take the symmetric part over all variables

```
symmPart[expr_, vars_] := Fold[(# + (# /. #2 -> -#2))/2 &, expr, vars] // Expand

pol = x y z^2 + x^2 y^2 + z^2;
symmPart[pol, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> x^2 y^2 + z^2
> ```

It works not only with polynomials

```
expr = Sin[x]^2 Cos[y] + Sin[x] Sin[y];
symmPart[expr, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> Cos[y] Sin[x]^2
> ```

Comment: I have learnt a lot from your answers. With respect, though I really like the idea of cancelling out terms, multinomial terms with even number of odd exponent variables, e.g. x^2yz, will not cancel. I understood the question to be collecting multinomial terms with variables with all even exponents.

Comment: @ubpdqn Oh, yes. This was my omission. I update my solution. Unfortunately now it is not so elegant.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
pol = d1^2 - d2^3 + d3^5 - d4^4 + d5^8;
```

Now collect terms with even powers as follows:

```
pol /. {(_^n_ | Times[-1, Power[_, n_]]) /; OddQ[n] :> Sequence[]}
```

Which gives:

```
d1^2 - d4^4 + d5^8
```

OR using `Cases` which gives you the terms as a `List`:

```
Cases[pol, (_^n_ | Times[-1, Power[_, n_]]) /; EvenQ[n]]
```

> `{d1^2, -d4^4, d5^8}`

Of course if you want it back as a polynomial you could just do

```
Plus @@ Cases[pol, (_^n_ | Times[-1, Power[_, n_]]) /; EvenQ[n]]
```

Comment: Going to post as answer - trivial mod to RunnyKine's answer here but can't format code in comment...

Answer (score 2):

Since OP did not provide a test case, let us use

```
poly = Plus @@ Table[Subscript[c, i] Subscript[g, i]
  d1^RandomInteger[{1, 4}] d2^RandomInteger[{1, 4}] d3^
  RandomInteger[{1, 4}] d4^RandomInteger[{1, 4}], {i, 30}];
```

The following code finds the cases to be gathered, factors them, and produces an expression equivalent to the input

```
Module[{terms = Union[Cases[poly, ___ d1^k1_?EvenQ d2^k2_?EvenQ d3^k3_?EvenQ d4^
   k4_?EvenQ :> {k1, k2, k3, k4}]]},
   terms = Cases[poly, f : _ d1^#[[1]] d2^#[[2]] d3^#[[3]] d4^#[[4]] :> f] & /@ terms;
   terms = Plus @@ Factor@Apply[Plus, terms, {1}];
   Expand[poly - terms] + terms]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach:

```
fun[pol_, var_] := Module[{p, ex, crit},
  p = pol[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[pol]];
  ex = Exponent[#, var] & /@ p;
  crit = And @@@ (EvenQ /@ ex);
  Plus @@ Pick[p, crit]
  ]
```

The first argument is expanded polynomial. The second argument is list of variables or single variable.

Test case (expanded) (x+y+z+w)^4,i.e.

```
f=w^4 + 4 w^3 x + 6 w^2 x^2 + 4 w x^3 + x^4 + 4 w^3 y + 12 w^2 x y + 
 12 w x^2 y + 4 x^3 y + 6 w^2 y^2 + 12 w x y^2 + 6 x^2 y^2 + 
 4 w y^3 + 4 x y^3 + y^4 + 4 w^3 z + 12 w^2 x z + 12 w x^2 z + 
 4 x^3 z + 12 w^2 y z + 24 w x y z + 12 x^2 y z + 12 w y^2 z + 
 12 x y^2 z + 4 y^3 z + 6 w^2 z^2 + 12 w x z^2 + 6 x^2 z^2 + 
 12 w y z^2 + 12 x y z^2 + 6 y^2 z^2 + 4 w z^3 + 4 x z^3 + 
 4 y z^3 + z^4
```

Applying:

```
fun[f, {x, y, z, w}]
```

yields:

```
w^4 + 6 w^2 x^2 + x^4 + 6 w^2 y^2 + 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4 + 6 w^2 z^2 + 
 6 x^2 z^2 + 6 y^2 z^2 + z^4
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler rule, if you just want to kill the odd-powered terms in the original expression, would be

`pol /. Power[_,_?OddQ]->0`

As ybeltukov pointed out this will not remove terms like x where the power is 1.  This can still by matching the OddQ matching powers...

```
Apply[#-(# /.Power[_,_?EvenQ]->0)&,{pol}]
```

or as a rule

```
pol /. expr_:>(expr-(expr /.Power[_,_?EvenQ]->0))
```

Comment: How about `x+x^2+x^3`? `x` will not be killed.

Comment: You're right, thinking...